# Problem aligning points near North Pole using Web Mercator with QGIS and Google Street View

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, web-mercator

This is my first time using QGIS 2.18.

I created a project with EPSG:3857.

Added OpenLayers Plug-in to use Google Street View as a map for the points and data I want to work on.

I love self-learning and learn-by-doing, I watched some vids and got an idea on how this program work.

I thought I'd make a sample to test if what I understood was right or not. I chose a point on Google Maps, right-clicked and chose "what's there" to get the coordinates. it is written as xxxxx.xxxxN, yyyyy.yyyyyE.

I added this in an excel file with 4 columns: ID, Name, Lat, Long. Saved as CSV. Opened it with notepad, saved as txt.

I then added a delimited text layer with the same ESPG:3857. The point in the file is almost at North Pole.

I tried to use some web-converters to know where the problem is but the best thing I got was like 400 km from the original location of my point.

My objective is to find a way to get coordinates from Google Maps, store in a text delimited file, add a text delimited layer and get the points where they should.

Can you help?

Comment: Can you show us the top few rows of your CSV file? You might have lon/lat around the wrong way.

Comment: EPSG:3857 is based on WGS 84 (that's its geographic CRS) but is actually "WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator" AKA "Web Mercator". Coordinates returned by QGIS are probably in 3857, meters, not latitude-longitude values (in degrees).

Comment: The North Pole is infinitely far away in Web Mercator, so I doubt any coordinates are going near it.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates you get from Google are pure, unprojected, geographic coordinates, which is EPSG:4326 or WGS 84. X coordinates (longitudes) are in the range between -180 and +180 degrees relative to the Greenwich meridian, Y coordinates (latitudes) are in the range between -90 and +90 degrees relative to the equator.

EPSG:3857 is a projected coordinate system, meaning "make the world flat so I can draw it on a flat display". X and Y Coordinates are both in the range approximately between -20 million and +20 million. The unit is meters at the equator, but far less than meters in other parts of the world. It would be zero at the poles, meaning this projection ist useless in the pole regions, and the common web maps exclude this regions.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to try to change columns for latitude and longitude, it's common mistake.